# How to setup proxy for webpack-dev-server for angular2-webpack-starter?

Tags: angular, webpack-dev-server, starter-kits

I have been porting an angular1 project to the angular2-webpack-starter project.   The front-end portion is working well enough that I attempted to connect the frontend to the backend server by setting up the proxy in the webpack.dev.js file as:

```
...
devServer: {
  proxy: {
    '/auth/*': {
      target: 'http://localhost:9000/auth/',
      secure: false
    }
  },
  port: METADATA.port,
  host: METADATA.host,
  historyApiFallback: true,
  watchOptions: {
    aggregateTimeout: 300,
    poll: 1000
  }
},
...
```

Something is clearly WRONG as: `http://localhost:3000/auth/local` is NOT proxied to the backend.  So your help would be greatly appreciated. Or is the proxy stuff for the webpack-dev-server not yet working???

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

```
devServer: {
      port: METADATA.port,
      host: METADATA.host,
      historyApiFallback: true,
      proxy: {
        "/api": "http://localhost:3100"
      },
      watchOptions: {
        aggregateTimeout: 300,
        poll: 1000
      }
    }
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow!  While you may have solved this user's problem, code-only answers are not very helpful to users who come to this question in the future.  Please edit your answer to explain why your code solves the original problem.